# java.io Socket to node.js

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a node.js command-line client for a semi-populated chat site "SpinChat". I've been doing a little research, and found that many java clients have been made using java.io. I however, wish to use node.js.

With Java.io, i can connect to a chat server like so:

```
new Socket("www.spinchat.com", 3001);
```

I need to be able to do with in node.js, and am not quite sure how. I wish i could provide more information... but I'm hoping the answer is really simple.. perhaps a node.js edition of java.io?

Comment: http://socket.io/ maybe?

Comment: `require('net').createServer()` ? `net.Socket` http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net

Answer (score 0):

According to [node.js docs](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html), you can open a socket like this

```
var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.connect(3001, "www.spinchat.com");
```

[Here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options) you can find additional details about the socket initialization and [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_connect_port_host_connectlistener) you can find additional detalis about the `connect()` function